# Ruby on Rails | String -> Links in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have a SQL function in my ROR model

```
def permit_needing_maps_link
rows = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("select dbo.NeedMapsList(#{self.CONO})").rows
rows.flatten![0] if !rows.empty?
end
```

That returns a comma delimited string like '1234, 5678, 9012'

Currently surfacing the results as a sidebar in admin/ like so:

```
sidebar :permits_needing_maps, only: :show do
resource.permit_needing_maps_link
end
```

Which does fine for surfacing the data. BUT question is, how can I now iterate through that string and turn them into ActiveAdmin links:

admin_well_master_path('1234'), admin_well_master_path('5678'), admin_well_master_path('9012'), etc.

I could update the function, or loop in code. Open to conventions. TIA

Comment: is permit_needing_maps_link returning array of strings?

Comment: @pavankumarv yes

Comment: ok if I understood right, permit_needing_maps_link function is giving you array of string Ex: ['123', '232', '234'], and now you want to use this array to generate link tags  which will be displayed in sidebar? like :- link1, link2, link3 and respectively redirects them to admin_well_master_path('123'), admin_well_master_path('232'), admin_well_master_path('234') ?

Comment: @pavankumarv yes

Comment: Did you try iterating over the string and putting out link_to tags?

Comment: and even if you do that what would you like to give the name of the link?

Comment: @pavankumarv admin_well_master_path('1234') is the activeadmin link name. Iterating over the string and adding tags is the literal ask of this ticket.

Answer (score 0):

OK upon understanding your question, and hoping you're receiving array of id's from the `resource.permit_needing_maps_link`

```
Ex: ['123', '232', '234'],
```

you can make these changes to your sidebar code

```
sidebar :permits_needing_maps, only: :show do
    ul do
      resource.permit_needing_maps_link.map { |id| li link_to id, admin_well_master_path(id) }
    end
end
```

**Explanation**

As we are getting the array of id's from the `resource.permit_needing_maps_link` like `['123', '234', '234']`

so inside sidebar I have opened an  `ul` tag and user `map` on `resource.permit_needing_maps_link` which will return `li` of `a` tag

currently I have kept the name the a as id itself, it's your call to make changes

Thank you.
Hope you find the similar results, for any error, please co-ordinate in the comments.
[image]